# Moxtra authorization to generate access_token fails

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am trying to embedded Moxtra chat functionality into my App.

For this I followed the steps mentioned into [OAuth 2 Authentication for Moxtra developer site](https://developer.moxtra.com/docs/docs-oauth/#uniqueid)

I was able to successfully registered my App in Moxtra and in response I got clientId and Secret key for it.

But when I follow **step 1) Begin authorization & request access token** (Client-Side (Implicit) Flow section in above link), it lands me to the page, which says below

***OAuth2 Error
There was a problem with the OAuth2 protocol (error="invalid_request", error_description="invalid_client")
Please go back to your client application and try again, or contact the owner and ask for support***

**Point to note**: Following is the format of uri I am using to get access_token.
**https://api.moxtra.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=123&response_type=token**
where instead of 123 (this is just for e:g) is my cliendId (trust me I am entering correct clientId).
and I have not used any request_uri, because the document states it as an optional parameter.

Please correct me if I am wrong with something above and let me know if you required anything more information.

Could someone please help me to get rid of this and help me to successfully generate the access_token. so I can move onto next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check if you created the app using the Moxtra Production or Sandbox environment. For Sandbox environment the endpoint URL is https://apisandbox.moxtra.com/ (https://developer.moxtra.com/docs/docs-oauth/#introduction)

Comment: Thanks !! ..answer accepted. Copy and paste is bad sometimes, I made mistake in the url.